# Login using email

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creating a very simple app, to learn Parse functionalities.
Along the way I realized I have to use only username and NOT email, (got this from a archived question, not sure if there are any changes made now).
But in my case the following is code returning true even if the input fields are null

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_activity);
        Parse.initialize(this, "#MASKED");

        emailLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        passwordLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        login_Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        signup_Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginSignup);

        signup_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        login_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = emailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = passwordLogin.getText().toString().trim();



                ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                   @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                            Toast.makeText(Login_activity.this,"Sucessfully Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                            Toast.makeText(Login_activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDiag = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login_activity.this);
                            alertDiag.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                            alertDiag.setTitle("Error");
                            alertDiag.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                            //AlertDialog dialog =
                                    alertDiag.create();
                            alertDiag.show();


                        }

                    }
                });





            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (e != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
```

Should be be:

```
if (e == null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
```

So if there is no exceptions the user has successfully logged in.

Also your code only checks for the email and password not username.